# Connect to Android TCP Server App from Internet (w/o Router): Impossible?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, server

I'm trying to write an Android app to accept TCP connections from the Internet. Sounds simple but despite weeks of head-banging, I've found no solution and now believe it impossible. I would love to have someone tell me I'm wrong.

I was encouraged by the "ServerSocket()" API function. I was able to create a listening socket (e.g. on port 2000) and connect to it from another app within my device. Unfortunately I find it is bound to (unrouteable) local address 10.0.0.150 which, of course, cannot be seen from the Internet.

I was also able to successfully connect by pointing my device to my local WIFI router and using the router's "Port Forwarding" feature to relay incoming connections to MyPublicIp:2000 to 10.0.0.150:2000. But this is not usable in the field (over an LTE connection) where I have no router.

I've searched StackOverflow and other sites but found no good answer (but plenty of inapplicable or obtuse ones).

From my reading, I hear that most (all?) carriers do not allow incoming connections to be routed to user devices, which may explain my dilemma.

PLEASE: Someone tell me I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible. 
Looking information about my mobile operator (mobile provider): it can provide a static IP address and my mobile device is available for incoming sessions, but only need to pay for this service.

Comment: Getting the IP address of my device is only a small part of the problem. I can find my device's public (DHCP) IP address in numerous ways, but I still can't connect because of the problem(s) as in my question. What carrier are you using?